# Calculus II - Volumes of Solids (Disks/Washers...)

Tags: calculus, volume, cross-sections

Could someone please clarify the process for finding the volume between two curves or under one curve? I understand that the volume (V) is the integral of the cross-sectional area (A), but I am a tad confused about the different cases and what makes something a "Disk" or a "Washer". Please correct me if I am wrong about the following:

1) The forumla is $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx$ when we are calculating the volume underneath one curve.

2) The formula is $\int_{a}^{b} (outer radius)^2 - (inner radius)^2 dx$ when calculating the volume between two curves.

Thanks!

Comment: your formulas refer to computing the volume of a solid obtained by rotating the curve $y=f(x)$ around the $x$ axis. In these cases the volume may be computed by summing tiny slices of the solid, taken normally to $x$ axis, which are disk of radius $f(x)$, thickness $dx$ and so of volume$\pi f(x)^2 dx$. It goes similarly for the second case in which you subtract the volume of the void cavity.

Comment: Here's a video of someone using a curve (the "template" piece near the bottom of the frame) to define a solid of rotation around an axis. The finished shape comes out at about 7 minutes into the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zF4IdMg5T3E  If you took a saw and made two cuts close to each other across the finished carved piece, perpendicular to the axis of turning, the thin piece of wood you cut out would be a disk.

Comment: It's important to remember that you are dealing with a three-dimensional object. There is no volume "underneath" or "between" curves, only volume inside the three-dimensional objects that you can define using curves and rotation.